# How do I have ctrl-shift-enter expand to www.(whatever).org in Firefox address bar?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Not long ago, Firefox would support the following shortcuts in the address bar, supposing you had typed `foo`:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> : `www.foo.org`
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> : `www.foo.net`
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> : `www.foo.com`

Only the last of these shortcuts is available as of now.

Is it possible to customize it? Is it possible to have the first two shortcuts back?

Comment: Just wanted to say the Firefox developers totally suck for making these kinds of changes without at least adding a preference to bring the normal functionality back. Only Mozilla could throw away 15 years' worth of established functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to customize it?

The TLD appended by the Ctrl+Enter shortcut is the value of `browser.fixup.alternate.suffix` in about:config.

> Is it possible to have the first two shortcuts back?

No. I'm sorry if the change in functionality disrupts your workflow.

---

Reference: Mozilla [bug 237027](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=237027#c120).